# List Child Pages of Parent Parent Page (Child pages from Grand Parent)

Tags: pages, listing

OK I'm doing a a menu (sidebar menu) that will display this all child pages of parent page (currently open)
Parent 
|-Child 1
|-Child 2
|*Child 3



but in same time when someone is in bolded page (child) will see the same thing

Parent 

|-Child 1

_* _|-Child 1
_ _|**-Child 2** 
_ _|- Child 3
|-Child 2
|-Child 3

currently I use next code which do first job well but not the second one with child of child I tried several things but nothing worked

```
 <?php if ( is_page() ) { 
if($post->post_parent)
$children = wp_list_pages('title_li=&child_of='.$post->post_parent.'&echo=0&sort_column=post_date&sort_order=DESC'); else
$children = wp_list_pages('title_li=&child_of='.$post->ID.'&echo=0&sort_column=post_date&sort_order=DESC');
if ($children) { ?> .......
```

Thanks in advance

---

### Edit

As Simon answered it worked but not for all cases and I edited so now final code is:

```
<?php if ( is_page() ) {
    $stats = count($post->ancestors);
if($post->post_parent){ 
  if($stats == 2){
    $children = wp_list_pages('title_li=&child_of='.get_post( $post->post_parent )->post_parent.'&echo=0&sort_column=post_date&sort_order=DESC&depth=1'); 
  }else{
    $children = wp_list_pages('title_li=&child_of='.$post->post_parent.'&echo=0&sort_column=post_date&sort_order=DESC&depth=1');
  }}
else{
  $children = wp_list_pages('title_li=&child_of='.$post->ID.'&echo=0&sort_column=post_date&sort_order=DESC&depth=1');
}
if ($children) { ?> ....
```

That's in case if somebody else need this stuff, Cheers and thanks for fast help

Comment: I'm not sure what you need to display ? Siblings to the viewed page or siblings of the parent page ?

Comment: I want to see first structure even when someone is on bold child page (in page of child of overall parent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you try this ? The idea is if there is a parent, we should list pages for the parent of this parent.

```
<?php if ( is_page() ) { 

    if($post->post_parent) {
        $children = wp_list_pages('title_li=&child_of='. get_post( $post->post_parent )->post_parent .'&echo=0&sort_column=post_date&sort_order=DESC'); 
    } else {
        $children = wp_list_pages('title_li=&child_of='.$post->ID.'&echo=0&sort_column=post_date&sort_order=DESC');
    }
}
```

Other solution would be to try to use `depth` option which according to codex could list only top-level pages :

```
<?php if ( is_page() ) { 

    if( $post->post_parent ) {
        $children = wp_list_pages('title_li=&depth=1&echo=0&sort_column=post_date&sort_order=DESC'); 
    } else {
        $children = wp_list_pages('title_li=&child_of='.$post->ID.'&echo=0&sort_column=post_date&sort_order=DESC');
    }
}
```

Sorry, I don't have time to try the code, but let us know if this is helps (or not).

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will get you going!

```
          <?php
          $children = wp_list_pages('title_li=&child_of='.$post->ID.'&echo=0&depth=1');
          if ($children) { ?>
          <?php echo $children; ?> 
          <?php } ?>
```

That will get you the child of the current page/template that is set in wp-admin.

Comment: yes I know that but it's displaying child what I want to find how to get a children from grand parent, so what I logically need to find out is get parent of current page (which I know to do) and from that parent page I want to find his parent (which I don't know how) and if there is a parent (last one) then display his children (sorry for bad english)